# S3 - Access Denied after uploading 100% image

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the CORS Configuration on S3

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is the Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Id": "<policyID>",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<stm>",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<id>:user/<name>"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My IAM user has the full access

[image: Full Access]

The Option request before the PUT returns a 200, so I am assuming the CORS has no configuration errors.

PUT request to the Signed URL for Uploading an image is returning with error

The image starts uploading, and the progress is as follows:

```
Upload progress: 56% Uploading 
Upload progress: 75% Uploading 
Upload progress: 84% Uploading 
Upload progress: 94% Uploading 
Upload progress: 100% Finalizing
Upload error: Upload error: 403
```

Response Error from amazonaws:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>REQid</RequestId><HostId>SomeID</HostId></Error>
```

After 100% Finalizing it throws a 403 error.
I am using [react-s3-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader) to upload the files to S3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used this library, but at a guess under the covers you won't be logged in as your AWS user. If that was the case, the `Principal` would be incorrect in the Bucket Policy. Does setting `"Principal":"*"` fix it?

Comment: I found the error. The error was on my end related to Public Access Settings for ACLs. I was marking "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects" True instead of False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error. The error was on my end related to Public Access Settings for ACLs. I was marking **Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects** True instead of False.